# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmd, process, windows-defender

This is my code:

```
    string damnfile = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(choofdlog.FileName);
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("% ProgramFiles %\\Windows Defender\\MpCmdRun.exe");
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
    startInfo.Arguments = "-Scan -ScanType 3 -File" + damnfile;
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo = startInfo;
    p.Start();
```

As you can see, I want to run WinDefender scan for a specific file, but it throws error that the process is not found, but this code works:

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("netstat");
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
        startInfo.Arguments = "-a";
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = startInfo;
        p.Start();
```

Also I want in the second code to redirect the cmd output to listBox, but thats the second problem, first help me with the defender scan please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solveded like now its opening, because I replaced

```
 ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("% ProgramFiles %\\Windows Defender\\MpCmdRun.exe");
```

with

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files\\Windows Defender\\MpCmdRun.exe");
```

Now appeared another problem: even I passed some arguments, the windows immediately close.